# Update all local branches with all remote branches

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-fetch

How do I override all local branches with all remote branches?

Here are my local branches:

```
client-side-js-framework
client-side-js-framework-2
client-side-js-framework-3
handlebars
master
```

And my remote branches:

```
client-side-js-framework
handlebars
master
no-network-connection
```

I want my local branches to mirror my remote branches as my remote branches are more up to date.  In other words, my local branches should be:

```
client-side-js-framework
handlebars
master
no-network-connection
```

Can this be done with one (or two) commands, rather than basically deleting my local repo, and re cloning it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, you should run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and then simply *delete* (most or all of) the local branches.  The next time you run, e.g.:

```
git checkout handlebars
```

your Git will search for your local name `handlebars`, fail to find it, search some more to see if there's exactly one name like `origin/handlebars` and `upstream/handlebars` and so on (one for each possible remote).

As long as there's *exactly* one such name, your Git will then say: *Aha, I should create local name `handlebars` using the **same commit** as remote-tracking name `origin/handlebars`.*  In that instant you will get a local branch named `handlebars` that matches `origin/handlebars`, Git will check it out, and you will be ready to work.  There's no need to drag half a dozen not-being-worked-on local names around like [a set of balls-and-chains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKekj.png).

If you really do need each branch updated, you must use a loop, with one update command per branch to do an appropriate merge and push, unless they're all fast-forward not-really-a-merge operations, in which case:

```
git fetch origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

will work—but *don't do it* (see the ball and chain link).

(It's a little trickier if you *do* have multiple remotes that use the same names.  In this case, `git checkout --track origin/handlebars` will achieve the desired result.  Meanwhile it's also tricky, and unwise, to let `git fetch` *delete* local names, but I think it can be done with `--prune`.)

Comment: I actually thought that was a link to documentation [sarcastically] named "set of balls-and-chains".  I didn't realize it was an image.  Well played.  I ended up deleting the local repo and re cloning it, but I like your answer, and will try to remember to do this instead next time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `git fetch origin`  will update your local branch as well as  add extra branch into your local repo, which is available on remote.

Alternative solution is

```
1. git checkout client-side-js-framework
2. git pull
```

That's all :)